# How to save video capture in mp4 format with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Guys I'm capturing the desktop video with opencv with python with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2                                           
from mss import mss                                  
from PIL import Image

bounding_box = {'top': 100, 'left': 0, 'width': 400, 'height': 300}

sct = mss()
                                                 
while True:
 sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)                     
 cv2.imshow('screen', np.array(sct_img))             
 if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  break
```

I want to be able to save this capture in mp4 format, how can I do this?

Comment: `cv2.VideoWriter(...)` but not all cobinations of `codec` and file extension can work. And if you define video format i.e. `800x600` then you have to resize image to this size before saving - if you use image with different size then it will create empty file.

Comment: example code which use `cv2.VideoWriter(...)` to record `frames` from webcam [record-file](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/record-file/main.py)

Comment: and in `VideoWriter` you set `FPS` - it doesn't mean how fast it will write it but how fast video will be displayed in video players. If you set `20 FPS` then you would have to write 20 frames in one second to get correct speed. if you write 10 frames in on second then video in player will run 2x faster. And if you write 40 frames in one second then player will write half speed.

Answer (score 0):

It should work something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2                                           
from mss import mss                                  
from PIL import Image

bounding_box = {'top': 100, 'left': 0, 'width': 400, 'height': 300}

sct = mss()
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
                                                
while True:
  sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)   
  out.write(np.array(sct_img))                  
  cv2.imshow('screen', np.array(sct_img))             
  if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation shows example in [Getting Started with Videos](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,  480))

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break

    frame = cv.flip(frame, 0)

    # write the flipped frame
    out.write(frame)

    cv.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

First you have to set codec using 4-chars code. There is page [fourcc.org](https://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) with codes.

Different systems may use different codecs - mostly `DIVX`, `XVID`, `MJPG`, `X264`, `WMV1`, `WMV2`.

```
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

Next you have to set filename with extension, `FPS`, width, height

```
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (400,  300))
```

Some codecs not work with some extensions - you may need to check different combinations (`.avi`, `.mp4`, `.mkv`, `.mov`, etc.)

If images have `400x300` and you want video `800x600` then set `VideoWriter(..., (800, 600))` but you also have to resize every frames before writing  because `VideoWriter` doesn't resize it automatically - it skip frames (without error) and finally it creates empty file (~4kb).

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800, 600))

out.write(frame)
```

`VideoWriter(.., 20.0, ...)` sets `20 FPS` (frames per second) but it is not speed of writing but it is information for video players how fast they have to display it.

If you create 20 frames in every second then player will display it in correct speed. If you create 10 frames in every second then player will display it 2x faster. If you create 40 frames in every second then player will displau it with half speed.

---

It uses program [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) and you can see list of codecs running in system console/terminal

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

or in source code (with 4-chars codes)

http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/isom_8c-source.html

Answer (score 0):

After I installed the ffmpeg codecs I was ale to write and read the .avi and .mp4 videos.  Do not leave out the 'isColor=' parameter.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
left_vid_path = r"E:\RECORD\newvid.mp4" #also works with .avi
output_L = cv2.VideoWriter(left_vid_path, fourcc, FPS, (1280, 800), isColor=False) 
output_L.write(frame)
```